# Related accounts tab shows old display names

Tags: support, linked-accounts

https://serverfault.com/users/58001/george-bailey?tab=accounts

If you click any of the images you will see it becomes George Bailey when the page loads but on the images on the accounts tab it still shows the old display name. How can this be fixed?

Comment: The flair on the accounts tab is quite heavily cached - when did you change your name?

Comment: I don't even see any related accounts, actually. But @ChrisF is correct - the flair doesn't update for a while when it comes to profile changes (display name and gravatar, basically). They might not change for days at a time, until at least you earn a badge on the site. That typically will trigger a refresh at around the end of the day.

Comment: @Grace - use the link in the question, not his MSO profile.

Comment: @ChrisF I did. It also shows nothing for me. See [esto](http://i.imgur.com/5irQc.png).

Comment: @Grace - he must have unlinked his accounts. It was showing for me when I checked before adding my comment.

Comment: Sorry about that.. I have been linking them and unlinking them trying to have two sets of related accounts..

Comment: It is OK now. They all match now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flair images are heavily cached, so it may take 24-48 hours for any profile changes to be visible in them.